# Intel x86-64 XSAVE/XRSTOR

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I'm a CS student writing in Intel x86-64 assembly, compiling with `nasm`, and running on an Core i7 processor with Ubuntu 12.04 as the guest OS.  Does anyone have an example of how to use `XSAVE` and `XRSTOR`?  I've read the section on `XSAVE` in Intel Architectures Software Developers manual several times.  I tried to implement `xsave` in C++ and then disassemble the binary to get an understanding of what it's doing.  And of course I've scoured the Internet for examples.  Any suggestions would be much obliged.

Comment: Are you asking what `XSAVE` and `XRSTOR` do, or how to use them?

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for your inquiry.  I'm more interested in the implementation.  My classmates and I are tired of the 100 or so lines of code it's taking us to backup the registries and restore them each assignment.  Not to mention XSAVE is probably a little more efficient than picking and choosing which registries to backup.

Comment: The implementation is hardware specific, but in general it takes values in the fpu and simd registers and stores/restores their values to/from memory.  You have to read *cpuid* information to know specifics about what your cpu stores and where.  It's primarily meant for operating systems to support fast context switching on processes.  Does that help?

Comment: Thanks.  I understand the process of checking for XSAVE support based on the CPUID flags but I don't know how to implement XSAVE.

Comment: Do you mean execute the instructions?  What registers are you trying to save/restore to/from memory?  Is your code userspace or kernelspace?  I'm not sure what you mean by *implement*.  The instructions are already implemented in hardware.

Comment: My goal is to backup the standard registers (rdi, rsi, rdx, rcx, etc) and the ymm registers.  By implementation I mean I don't know how to actually use XSAVE and XRSTOR in my personal code.  In each assignment I spend about 100 lines of code pushing registers onto the stack and popping them off when my function is done.  I don't really understand what operand to supply XSAVE.  Is it something like:

XSAVE    [rsp]

My problem is I'm new to Intel assembly (assembly as a whole) and I don't know how to interpret the Intel manual as far as how to use the instruction.

Comment: Ah, I think what you're looking for are assembler macros.  `XSAVE`/`XRSTOR` are generally meant for kernel space operation.  For example, *masm* has a `USING` declaration which will save and restore registers for functions.  If you're using *yasm*, you can define [macros](http://www.tortall.net/projects/yasm/manual/html/manual.html#nasm-macro-rotate).  I'll add a quick writeup as an answer.  Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally, an answer to this question.  Thanks to user: harold who helped answer the question for me.  A summary of what I've found:

Set up a memory space in .data and align it on a 64-byte boundary.  Then you can use the commands with that memory space.  If you want to use the stack, you should be able to do so similarly ensuring that the stack is 64-byte aligned, but this way seems easier to me for this purpose.

eax: edx is used to set the flags of which registers you WANT to save, restore.  This combined is 64-bits and is ANDed with an internal control which knows which registers you CAN save/restore (this allows processors that don't have ymm for example to ignore those registers)  I find it easiest to just set all bits on and save / restore everything:

segment .data

```
align   64
regsave times 1024 dq 0
```

segment .text

```
mov     rdx, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
mov     rax, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
xsave   [regsave]

vzeroall

mov     rdx, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
mov     rax, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
xrstor  [regsave]
```

Comment: (The vzeroall is just an example of interim code that alters the registers.)

Comment: Brilliant!  Thank you C_Rod and Harold.  The code works great.  I was expecting the command to backup the general purpose registers but apparently it's only the floating point registers that get backed up.  Between this and Jason's reply we should be able to backup both rather efficiently.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

The `xsave`/`xrstor`/`xsaveopt` instructions are used to perform a full save/restore of the extended state in the processor to/from memory.  Similar to `fxsave`/`fxrstor`, it saves/restores fpu state `st[0..7]`, `xmm[0..7]`, `mxcsr`, etc... in addition to supporting `ymm[0..15]` and future extensions (`zmm[0..31]`).  The actual values saved, and the data layout are enumerated via the relevant `cpuid` leaves.  The use is generally operating system [context switching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch).  The [programmer reference](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) describes how to use them correctly.

For general userspace register save/restore, the assembler usually has a facility for saving/restoring a set of registers.

For example...

### masm

```
foo PROC USES eax,ebx,ecx
    xor    ebx, ebx

loop:
    mov    eax, [esi + ebx*4]
    mov    [edi + ebx*4], eax
    inc    ebx
    dec    ecx

    jnz    loop

    ret

foo ENDP
```

### yasm

```
%macro  mpush 1-*

  %rep  %0
        push    %1
  %rotate 1
  %endrep

%endmacro

%macro  mpop 1-*

  %rep %0
  %rotate -1
        pop     %1
  %endrep

%endmacro
```

```
foo:
    mpush  rax,rbx,rcx
    xor    rbx, rbx

loop:
    mov    rax, [rsi + rbx*8]
    mov    [rdi + rbx*8], rax
    inc    rbx
    dec    rcx

    jnz    loop

    mpop   rax,rbx,rcx
    ret
```

In ia-32, there is a `pushad` to save all the general purpose registers, but with amd64 you need to have corresponding `push`/`pop` pairs for each of the registers you use.

Comment: This is great, thanks Jason.  I'm in the middle of midterms so I'll digest your response as soon as I can.  I'm still curious about XSAVE and XRSTOR if anyone has any examples.  I noticed gcc 4.8 now has -XSAVE and -XRSTOR flags.  I haven't got it to work but I'm guessing gcc just wraps your code in the appropriate assembly instructions.  Seems like I should be able to compile with those args and view the assembly.

Comment: No problem.  The compiler options are just to let the compiler know it can emit the instructions.  There are probably intrinsics you'll need to look up in the compiler reference to actually use them, unless you write the assembly.  Probably, the best place to find a good example of `xrstor`/`xsave`/`xsaveopt` being used is the linux kernel source itself.  Good luck on your midterms.