# Intel x86 using XSAVE and XRSTOR

Tags: assembly, x86-64, intel

This question is in reference to:

[Intel x86-64 XSAVE/XRSTOR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22105247/intel-x86-64-xsave-xrstor)

This question is about how to use XSAVE and XRSTOR.  Unfortunately, due to the very odd reputation system on this site, I can't simply ask my question on that thread, I have to make a new question.  One person answered this question but did not use the Intel x86 commands XSAVE and XRSTOR.  So, really, the question wasn't answered.

Is there some way anyone can put a single example of how to use XSAVE and XRSTOR so that we don't have to copy every register to memory individually to preserve it.

Right now we have to:

```
copy xmm0 to memory, copy xmm1 to memory... and so on
```

Then:

```
right shift ymm0 64 bytes, right shift ymm1 64 bytes... and so on
```

Then:

```
repeat 3 times.
```

So to save the ymm registers, we need about 100 commands.

Then to restore them is about the same.

Now, it seems that Intel x86 assembly has an instruction to do this all at once.  The command in Intel x86 syntax is:

```
xsave [mem], flag
```

and

```
xrstor [mem], flag
```

So, I should be able to (e.g.) just reserve memory in the .data segment like so:

```
regsave times 1024 dq 0
```

and then say

```
xsave [regsave], flag
```

What is flag?  In the huge assembly manual (which has no examples) it says that any registers that can be saved will be ANDed with the flag to determine which ones WILL be saved.  It says the flag is 32 bits.  So I SHOULD be able to just say:

```
xsave [regsave], 0xFFFFFFFF
```

and have it save any registers that it can.

This unfortunately doesn't work.  The code will not assemble and gives the error:

> "error: invalid combination of opcode and operands"

Comment: Linux kernel uses explicit byte codes (x86 machine code): http://lwn.net/Articles/281921/ `__asm__ __volatile__(".byte " REX_PREFIX "0x0f,0xae,0x27"`

Comment: This isn't the right place to complain about Stack Overflow. If you have a grievance, post it on Meta. Keep this post to the point.

Comment: Not sure where you have found that the format of the instruction is `xsave [mem], flag` and that flag is 32 bits. In fact if you look up the relevant section in the instruction set reference, you can see it says: `The implicit EDX:EAX register pair specifies a 64-bit instruction mask. `

Comment: What is Meta?  I found the inability to ask my question a bit annoying, but I also wanted to explain that I wasn't mindlessly copying an existing question, that is, there was a reason for it.  @osgx Thanks for the tip.  I'll take a look.

Comment: @Jester Yeah, I did see that in section 13.  And actually, I thought that's where the format was.  I've been looking for this answer for days.  Hours and hours of searching has given me tips but it's amazing how hard it is to get info about assembly.  So you're saying I would essentially combine the low ends of rdx:rax to get the flag set.  What would the command be then?

Comment: @osgx the link you sent seems to be in c code.  Actually, it occurs to me your format looks like it is using intrinsics.  I'm actually looking for Intel assembly code to do this.  Thanks for helping, though.

Comment: @C_Rod `xsave [something]`, load `edx` and `eax` any way you want

Comment: @harold  Thanks.  That made the command work.  I'm getting closer.  It caused a segmentation fault when I used it though.  I also tried subtracting from rsp and using the stack (I did 2048 even though it shouldn't need near that and then added it back afterwards)  I comment out the command and everything runs but when I try it, it causes a segfault.  Anything I need to be aware of in terms of alignment or anything else that might cause this?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @C_Rod yes, the address has to be 64-byte aligned

Comment: @harold  That worked perfectly.  Thanks so much for your input.  If you would like to make an answer with that info, I'll upvote it for you.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

XSAVE / XRSTOR doesn't have a parameters for flag, only memory location,

the spec is:

```
XSAVE mem
XRSTOR mem
```

the values in EDX:EAX specified which components to save/restore to the memory.