# Save value of xmm registers

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm a little surprised I couldn't find much information on this.

If we want to save/restore the values of the general purpose registers we can use `pushad`/`popad`.

Is there a similar way to save/restore **ALL** of the xmm registers?

Comment: It's not like it's not written in the instruction set reference ... see `FXSAVE`. PS: `pusha/popa` is no longer available in 64 bit mode.

Comment: Try `fxsave` or the newer `xsave`.

Comment: As @fuz wrote, [`XSAVE`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/XSAVE.html) may be helpful to you, because it does save almost all registers to a memory area - pretty similar to `PUSHA`, but more extensive.

Comment: Both FXSAVE and XSAVE do more than just save the XMM registers and are meant to be used by operating systems. In particular using XSAVE requires operating support. The fastest way to save and restore just the XMM registers is would be to just write them one by one to memory (eg. `sub esp,8*16` `mov 0[esp],xmm0` `mov 16[esp],xmm1`...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to save the XMM/YMM registers to memory you have 2 options:

**A: use [(F)](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/FXSAVE.html)[XSAVE](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/XSAVE.html) / [(F)](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/FXRSTOR.html)[XRSTOR](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/XRSTOR.html)**, see: [Intel x86-64 XSAVE/XRSTOR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22105247/intel-x86-64-xsave-xrstor)

You'll need the latest CPU for this.

> ```
> ;save:
> mov     rdx, -1              
> mov     rax, -1                 ;save all possible regs
> xsave   [location]
>
> ...some code that alters the registers
> ;restore:
> mov     rdx, -1
> mov     rax, -1
> xrstor  [location]
> ```

**B: manually save the regs to memory**

The other option is to simply store the contents of the registers in memory.
Let's assume you want to store your data on the stack.
This approach will work on any CPU and is much more portable, for the next decade at least this would be my favoured approach.

**Quick and dirty unaligned save**

```
;push xmm0
lea rsp,[rsp-16*numOfRegsToSave]          ;reserve space on the stack
vmovdqu [rsp+16*0],xmm0                   ;push a register (note unaligned! write) 
vmovdqu [rsp+16*1],xmm1                   ;keep pushing
.......

;pop xmm0
.......
vmovdqu xmm1,[rsp+16*1]                   ;pop registers in reverse order
vmovdqu xmm0,[rsp+16*0]                   ;first 'pop' the register
lea rsp,[rsp+16*numOfRegsToSave]          ;then update the stack.
```

If you have lots of registers to save, you'll want to align the stack on a 32 byte boundary:

**Slightly faster code (at the cost of one clobbered register)**

```
mov rbp,rsp                       ;save the stack pointer
and rsp,-32                       ;align on a 32 byte boundary
;push ymm0
lea rsp,[rsp-32*numOfRegsToSave] ;reserve space on the stack
vmovdqa [rsp+32],ymm0             ;push a register (note aligned! write)
.......

;pop ymm0
....
vmovdqa ymm0,[rsp+32]
mov rsp,rbp
```

Always push any ymm registers first and any other registers later (in decreasing order of size), that way the stack will always be aligned optimally.

Note that `pushad/popad` are no longer supported on x64.

Comment: You left out the part where you figure out the size of the XSAVE buffer, give it 64-byte alignment and initialize the XSAVE header. Also why save everything when the question asks only how to save the XMM registers? Just saving the SSE state would mean you could use a fixed size buffer, since you're only using the legacy part of the XSAVE buffer, and so don't need calculate its size at run time.

Comment: @Johan
Hey. Either I filled the remaining offsets wrong or there is a little bug in your implementation. In my example I wanted to store xmm0, xmm1, xmm2, xmm3. I sub rsp 16*4. Now if i move registers content on stack starting with vmovdqu [rsp+16*1],xmm0 then i end up doing rsp+16*4 which overrides previous stack content. I believe this should be vmovdqu [rsp+16*0],xmm0   vmovdqu [rsp+16*1],xmm1  etc.

Comment: Note that this will not work on any CPU as `vmovdqu` is an AVX instruction. However you can use `movdqu` which does the exact same thing a bit slower and that's an SSE2 instruction, guaranteed to be on all x-86-64 CPUs